# Story about people going inside other's bodies to cure illness

Tags: story-identification

I've read this story something around 5 years ago, and it seemed to be pretty recent.

The story was about a teenager who had the ability to get inside other people's body, to cure them.
If I remember correctly, that ability was inherited from his father.

When he is inside someone else's body, we can see that the different cells in the human body organized themselves has a society, and most (if not all) of them were humanoids.

I also remember something of a romance between the main character and a leucocyte.

I also remember that one of the friend of the main character was suffering from brittle bone disease, and towards the end of the book we learn that he is also able to get into other people's body.

The people with the ability to get into other people's body were working under an association, and were trying to prevent some kind of conspiracy.